# Spectrum of operator A

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A \in B(H)$. How to prove that if
$|\lambda| = \|A\|$ and $\lambda \in W(A)$, then $\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)$?

Here $W(A)$ is the numerical range of the operator $A$:
$$W(A):= \big\{(Ax,x): \|x\| = 1\big\}$$
and $\sigma_p(A)$ is the point spectrum of $A$.

I have no idea how to prove this.  Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

There is $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that
$$
\lambda = \langle Ax,x\rangle.
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$
|\langle Ax,x\rangle| \le \|A\|= |\lambda|
$$
with equality if and only if $Ax$ and $x$ are linearly dependent. This implies that $Ax$ and $x$ are linearly dependent: $c_1 Ax = c_2 x$. Since $x\ne0$, it follows $c_1\ne0$, and $x$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $c_2/c_1$. Multiplying the equation with $x$ implies
$c_1 \lambda = c_2$, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.